# How to work with edge Texture

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, textures, transformation

Im not sure if i use the right terms, but im not able to find something to start with.

Im trying to develop a little HTML5 game. I have a ground with a texture and now I want to make a surrounding texture. The texture is an image wich should be bend around the ground.

At the moment im using [easelJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/EaselJS) for display my images/textures. So im looking for some sort of Tutorial/Script/Advice. Im not even sure if I can bend a image in javascript. So the worst case I can think of is split the image in 100 pieces and then put it back together and rotate each piece.

for example like this:

[image: edge Texture]

Comment: Are you asking about how to make a grass layer to follow your ground? Cos it's hard to see the idea on your picture.

Comment: yes the question is how i can bend the image to fit the ground

Comment: Take a look at this question, it looks similar to yours: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/15302/how-can-i-get-textures-on-edge-of-walls-like-in-super-metroid-and-aquaria

Comment: @KromStern I don't think so - that question presumes a tile-based rendering. This question appears to be talking about curving images (i.e. spline based terrain). Perhaps the OP could clarify. I think it's a tricky problem, but pertinent to game-development certainly.

Comment: yes im looking for a way to curve the image on a spline

Comment: The linked duplicate does not appear to presume tile-based at all, nor does the solution.